# Wrong calculation with matrix exponential (MatrixExp)

Tags: matrix

I've been doing some calcultations on mathematica which involve exponential of matrices. It's well known that if [A,B]=0 then [A,F(B)]=0 where A,B are matrices and [,] is their commutator. Nonetheless, I have a matrix A, which commutes with B and then I know that [A,MatrixExp[B]]=0, but Mathematica gives me a non-zero matrix... I've tried to chop it and it didn't work. So, what could be the source of this error? I checked for the commutator of [A,B] and Mathematica is indeed giving 0. Here is a picture of the matrix plot of the output:

[image]

I have a Hamiltonian which is parity invariant and the evolution operator U is not commuting with the parity operator (U=exp(-iHt)) and [Pi,H]=0.

Note: both operators have norm 1.

(Of course, this is just a sanity check of a much bigger calculation that is going wrong, I have a Hamiltonian which is parity invariant and the evolution operator U is not commuting with the parity operator).

Here are the two matrices:

```
A = SparseArray[{{1,1}->1,{2,33}->1,{3,17}->1,{4,49}->1,{5,9}->1,{6,41}->1,{7,25}->1,{8,57}->1,{9,5}->1,{10,37}->1,{11,21}->1,{12,53}->1,{13,13}->1,{14,45}->1,{15,29}->1,{16,61}->1,{17,3}->1,{18,35}->1,{19,19}->1,{20,51}->1,{21,11}->1,{22,43}->1,{23,27}->1,{24,59}->1,{25,7}->1,{26,39}->1,{27,23}->1,{28,55}->1,{29,15}->1,{30,47}->1,{31,31}->1,{32,63}->1,{33,2}->1,{34,34}->1,{35,18}->1,{36,50}->1,{37,10}->1,{38,42}->1,{39,26}->1,{40,58}->1,{41,6}->1,{42,38}->1,{43,22}->1,{44,54}->1,{45,14}->1,{46,46}->1,{47,30}->1,{48,62}->1,{49,4}->1,{50,36}->1,{51,20}->1,{52,52}->1,{53,12}->1,{54,44}->1,{55,28}->1,{56,60}->1,{57,8}->1,{58,40}->1,{59,24}->1,{60,56}->1,{61,16}->1,{62,48}->1,{63,32}->1,{64,64}->1}];
B = -I*SparseArray[{{1,1}->5,{2,2}->3,{2,3}->2,{3,2}->2,{3,3}->1,{3,5}->2,{4,4}->3,{4,6}->2,{5,3}->2,{5,5}->1,{5,9}->2,{6,4}->2,{6,6}->-1,{6,7}->2,{6,10}->2,{7,6}->2,{7,7}->1,{7,11}->2,{8,8}->3,{8,12}->2,{9,5}->2,{9,9}->1,{9,17}->2,{10,6}->2,{10,10}->-1,{10,11}->2,{10,18}->2,{11,7}->2,{11,10}->2,{11,11}->-3,{11,13}->2,{11,19}->2,{12,8}->2,{12,12}->-1,{12,14}->2,{12,20}->2,{13,11}->2,{13,13}->1,{13,21}->2,{14,12}->2,{14,14}->-1,{14,15}->2,{14,22}->2,{15,14}->2,{15,15}->1,{15,23}->2,{16,16}->3,{16,24}->2,{17,9}->2,{17,17}->1,{17,33}->2,{18,10}->2,{18,18}->-1,{18,19}->2,{18,34}->2,{19,11}->2,{19,18}->2,{19,19}->-3,{19,21}->2,{19,35}->2,{20,12}->2,{20,20}->-1,{20,22}->2,{20,36}->2,{21,13}->2,{21,19}->2,{21,21}->-3,{21,25}->2,{21,37}->2,{22,14}->2,{22,20}->2,{22,22}->-5,{22,23}->2,{22,26}->2,{22,38}->2,{23,15}->2,{23,22}->2,{23,23}->-3,{23,27}->2,{23,39}->2,{24,16}->2,{24,24}->-1,{24,28}->2,{24,40}->2,{25,21}->2,{25,25}->1,{25,41}->2,{26,22}->2,{26,26}->-1,{26,27}->2,{26,42}->2,{27,23}->2,{27,26}->2,{27,27}->-3,{27,29}->2,{27,43}->2,{28,24}->2,{28,28}->-1,{28,30}->2,{28,44}->2,{29,27}->2,{29,29}->1,{29,45}->2,{30,28}->2,{30,30}->-1,{30,31}->2,{30,46}->2,{31,30}->2,{31,31}->1,{31,47}->2,{32,32}->3,{32,48}->2,{33,17}->2,{33,33}->3,{34,18}->2,{34,34}->1,{34,35}->2,{35,19}->2,{35,34}->2,{35,35}->-1,{35,37}->2,{36,20}->2,{36,36}->1,{36,38}->2,{37,21}->2,{37,35}->2,{37,37}->-1,{37,41}->2,{38,22}->2,{38,36}->2,{38,38}->-3,{38,39}->2,{38,42}->2,{39,23}->2,{39,38}->2,{39,39}->-1,{39,43}->2,{40,24}->2,{40,40}->1,{40,44}->2,{41,25}->2,{41,37}->2,{41,41}->-1,{41,49}->2,{42,26}->2,{42,38}->2,{42,42}->-3,{42,43}->2,{42,50}->2,{43,27}->2,{43,39}->2,{43,42}->2,{43,43}->-5,{43,45}->2,{43,51}->2,{44,28}->2,{44,40}->2,{44,44}->-3,{44,46}->2,{44,52}->2,{45,29}->2,{45,43}->2,{45,45}->-1,{45,53}->2,{46,30}->2,{46,44}->2,{46,46}->-3,{46,47}->2,{46,54}->2,{47,31}->2,{47,46}->2,{47,47}->-1,{47,55}->2,{48,32}->2,{48,48}->1,{48,56}->2,{49,41}->2,{49,49}->3,{50,42}->2,{50,50}->1,{50,51}->2,{51,43}->2,{51,50}->2,{51,51}->-1,{51,53}->2,{52,44}->2,{52,52}->1,{52,54}->2,{53,45}->2,{53,51}->2,{53,53}->-1,{53,57}->2,{54,46}->2,{54,52}->2,{54,54}->-3,{54,55}->2,{54,58}->2,{55,47}->2,{55,54}->2,{55,55}->-1,{55,59}->2,{56,48}->2,{56,56}->1,{56,60}->2,{57,53}->2,{57,57}->3,{58,54}->2,{58,58}->1,{58,59}->2,{59,55}->2,{59,58}->2,{59,59}->-1,{59,61}->2,{60,56}->2,{60,60}->1,{60,62}->2,{61,59}->2,{61,61}->3,{62,60}->2,{62,62}->1,{62,63}->2,{63,62}->2,{63,63}->3,{64,64}->5}]/10;
```

Comment: Can you please compute & note the `Norm` of $\Pi$, $U$, and the commutator? From the color scale it looks like the latter will be very small, and the nonzero commutator could be due to double-precision numerical accuracy artefacts ($10^{-16}$ scale).

Comment: I tell from the color bar that the plotted matrix is indistinguishable from the zero matrix in machine precision.

Comment: Both of the norms of these operators are 1(both are unitary) and Mathematica indeed gives 1.

Comment: Again, can you please note the norm of the commutator?

Comment: Best would be to provide also the two matrices in copyable form.

Comment: But what's the proper way to fix it? I'd want this to be zero. But since I`m using this guys in a bunch of matrix multiplications the errors accumulate and in the end produce unreasonable results. I have some plots which range from 0 to 1, the plots should be zero at every point for a parity invariant H, but they give a plot close to 0.4   most of the time... Which is clearly wrong. Should I think that there's another source of errors which is not this one?

Comment: This means your numerical scheme is unstable. Look for a better (stable) propagation scheme, they exist.

Comment: @MarceloBroinizi "Should I think that there's another source of errors which is not this one?" If I have to guess: Yes. (But without the actual matrices that you used, how should I tell?) As Roman pointed out, you are likely using an instable numerical scheme in which even tiny errors may accumulate.

Comment: Unfortunately it says the raw input format of the matrices is too big to fit in Mathematica.SE editor. These are matrices with 2^8 elements

Comment: @MarceloBroinizi Then paste them in a pastebin. 2^8 = 256; that's hardly a big matrix by any measure.

Comment: I managed to paste em in Wolfram cloud!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the claim that `Chop[a.MatrixExp[b] - MatrixExp[b].a]` is non-zero with `a` and `b` taken from the links you included.

Comment: The first matrix is already exponentiated! I mean, the first link is indeed exp[b]

Comment: The norm of $A$ is indeed 1; but the norm of $B$ is only $0.997431$ (yet it's purely imaginary, so `Norm[MatrixExp[B]] == 1`). Could this lead to your errors? Other than that I confirm that $[A,B]=0$.

Comment: Thanks mate. Did you check it using the Norm[]  function?

Comment: Yes, by defining `B` without `N` (exact numbers) and then computing `Norm[B]`. Maybe this doesn't matter though; I'm just wondering if there's a mistake somewhere as you claimed the norm of `B` was 1.

Comment: @Roman It's possible I put the wrong matrix in for B. It was just the rationalized version of the MatrixLog of the matrix Marcelo put in the cloud.

Comment: @CarlWoll that's not the problem, your rationalization is very accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this problem. Defining the exact matrices from your upload (only removing the imaginary unit)

```
A = SparseArray[{{1,1}->1,{2,33}->1,{3,17}->1,{4,49}->1,{5,9}->1,{6,41}->1,{7,25}->1,{8,57}->1,{9,5}->1,{10,37}->1,{11,21}->1,{12,53}->1,{13,13}->1,{14,45}->1,{15,29}->1,{16,61}->1,{17,3}->1,{18,35}->1,{19,19}->1,{20,51}->1,{21,11}->1,{22,43}->1,{23,27}->1,{24,59}->1,{25,7}->1,{26,39}->1,{27,23}->1,{28,55}->1,{29,15}->1,{30,47}->1,{31,31}->1,{32,63}->1,{33,2}->1,{34,34}->1,{35,18}->1,{36,50}->1,{37,10}->1,{38,42}->1,{39,26}->1,{40,58}->1,{41,6}->1,{42,38}->1,{43,22}->1,{44,54}->1,{45,14}->1,{46,46}->1,{47,30}->1,{48,62}->1,{49,4}->1,{50,36}->1,{51,20}->1,{52,52}->1,{53,12}->1,{54,44}->1,{55,28}->1,{56,60}->1,{57,8}->1,{58,40}->1,{59,24}->1,{60,56}->1,{61,16}->1,{62,48}->1,{63,32}->1,{64,64}->1}];
B = SparseArray[{{1,1}->5,{2,2}->3,{2,3}->2,{3,2}->2,{3,3}->1,{3,5}->2,{4,4}->3,{4,6}->2,{5,3}->2,{5,5}->1,{5,9}->2,{6,4}->2,{6,6}->-1,{6,7}->2,{6,10}->2,{7,6}->2,{7,7}->1,{7,11}->2,{8,8}->3,{8,12}->2,{9,5}->2,{9,9}->1,{9,17}->2,{10,6}->2,{10,10}->-1,{10,11}->2,{10,18}->2,{11,7}->2,{11,10}->2,{11,11}->-3,{11,13}->2,{11,19}->2,{12,8}->2,{12,12}->-1,{12,14}->2,{12,20}->2,{13,11}->2,{13,13}->1,{13,21}->2,{14,12}->2,{14,14}->-1,{14,15}->2,{14,22}->2,{15,14}->2,{15,15}->1,{15,23}->2,{16,16}->3,{16,24}->2,{17,9}->2,{17,17}->1,{17,33}->2,{18,10}->2,{18,18}->-1,{18,19}->2,{18,34}->2,{19,11}->2,{19,18}->2,{19,19}->-3,{19,21}->2,{19,35}->2,{20,12}->2,{20,20}->-1,{20,22}->2,{20,36}->2,{21,13}->2,{21,19}->2,{21,21}->-3,{21,25}->2,{21,37}->2,{22,14}->2,{22,20}->2,{22,22}->-5,{22,23}->2,{22,26}->2,{22,38}->2,{23,15}->2,{23,22}->2,{23,23}->-3,{23,27}->2,{23,39}->2,{24,16}->2,{24,24}->-1,{24,28}->2,{24,40}->2,{25,21}->2,{25,25}->1,{25,41}->2,{26,22}->2,{26,26}->-1,{26,27}->2,{26,42}->2,{27,23}->2,{27,26}->2,{27,27}->-3,{27,29}->2,{27,43}->2,{28,24}->2,{28,28}->-1,{28,30}->2,{28,44}->2,{29,27}->2,{29,29}->1,{29,45}->2,{30,28}->2,{30,30}->-1,{30,31}->2,{30,46}->2,{31,30}->2,{31,31}->1,{31,47}->2,{32,32}->3,{32,48}->2,{33,17}->2,{33,33}->3,{34,18}->2,{34,34}->1,{34,35}->2,{35,19}->2,{35,34}->2,{35,35}->-1,{35,37}->2,{36,20}->2,{36,36}->1,{36,38}->2,{37,21}->2,{37,35}->2,{37,37}->-1,{37,41}->2,{38,22}->2,{38,36}->2,{38,38}->-3,{38,39}->2,{38,42}->2,{39,23}->2,{39,38}->2,{39,39}->-1,{39,43}->2,{40,24}->2,{40,40}->1,{40,44}->2,{41,25}->2,{41,37}->2,{41,41}->-1,{41,49}->2,{42,26}->2,{42,38}->2,{42,42}->-3,{42,43}->2,{42,50}->2,{43,27}->2,{43,39}->2,{43,42}->2,{43,43}->-5,{43,45}->2,{43,51}->2,{44,28}->2,{44,40}->2,{44,44}->-3,{44,46}->2,{44,52}->2,{45,29}->2,{45,43}->2,{45,45}->-1,{45,53}->2,{46,30}->2,{46,44}->2,{46,46}->-3,{46,47}->2,{46,54}->2,{47,31}->2,{47,46}->2,{47,47}->-1,{47,55}->2,{48,32}->2,{48,48}->1,{48,56}->2,{49,41}->2,{49,49}->3,{50,42}->2,{50,50}->1,{50,51}->2,{51,43}->2,{51,50}->2,{51,51}->-1,{51,53}->2,{52,44}->2,{52,52}->1,{52,54}->2,{53,45}->2,{53,51}->2,{53,53}->-1,{53,57}->2,{54,46}->2,{54,52}->2,{54,54}->-3,{54,55}->2,{54,58}->2,{55,47}->2,{55,54}->2,{55,55}->-1,{55,59}->2,{56,48}->2,{56,56}->1,{56,60}->2,{57,53}->2,{57,57}->3,{58,54}->2,{58,58}->1,{58,59}->2,{59,55}->2,{59,58}->2,{59,59}->-1,{59,61}->2,{60,56}->2,{60,60}->1,{60,62}->2,{61,59}->2,{61,61}->3,{62,60}->2,{62,62}->1,{62,63}->2,{63,62}->2,{63,63}->3,{64,64}->5}]/10;
```

we see that the commutator vanishes exactly,

```
A.B - B.A // Norm
```

> 0

With the numerical matrix exponential

```
U = MatrixExp[-I*B // N];
```

the commutator vanishes to numerical precision,

```
A.U - U.A // Norm
```

> 8.32424*10^-16

and even multiplying `U` a million times with itself (to simulate your propagation) still commutes with `A` pretty well:

```
F = Nest[U.# &, IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[U]], 10^6];
A.F - F.A // Norm
```

> 4.40179*10^-13

I suspect there's some other bug in your code.